# Control Panel Sound Settings Keep Switching Back After Reboot of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, control-panel

Every time I reboot my computer the Control Panel -> Sound settings switch back to their default-install state.  See the attached screen capture below.  I can change the default Playback device to Speakers, and it works great.  That is, until I reboot.  Then the default Playback device is AMD HDMI Output again.  This happens every time I reboot the computer.  How can I fix it, so that the default Playback device doesn't get modified when I reboot?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using the HMDI audio output, disable it. (Right click -> Disable)

Comment: Also, quick check of the BIOS for your sound, if your using the boards onboard sound. **My BIOS had an option for the onboard audio called "Auto," which was selected. Flipping this to "On" instead solved my issue.** http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=191113